# remove favorite and ignore tags

Tags: discussion, ignored-tags, tag-watching

how does one remove a favorite tag or an ignore tag?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any page which lists your favorite or ignored tags, such as on the main page, click the edit link and then the `x` to the right of the tag. Alternatively, for favorite tags, you can click the gold star that appears when you hover over the tag to unfavorite it.

Comment: oh yes. i have poor vision and it's hard to see the x's.

Comment: @Ray: FYI: you can also do this through the "prefs" tab in your user profile.