# Add an edit mode for favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching

It happened a few times that I accidentally clicked the [image: x] on a favourite tag, which removed that tag. Sometimes I open multiple tag pages, without knowing which tag I just removed. Some other time it's not a big deal since I know which tag I wanted to click, so I could add again. However it goes down to the very bottom of the list then, which was previously ordered in some way, with related tags close together. Grouping tags by categories or my own priority is useful, searching the list for an often used tag is annoying. Since there is [no real way to order the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87042/reorder-favorite-ignored-tags), tag management is annoying. Annoyingness grows linearly to the amount of tags.

I doubt that most users change their favourite tags too often. I think it's not necessary for the [image: x] to be always accessible when the main purpose of a tag is to click it for listing questions with that tag.

I propose to hide the [image: x] of each tag and to add an *edit* link below the favourite tags. When clicking that edit link, the [image: x] should reappear on each tag. Additionally the tags shouldn't be clickable any more but be draggable to a new position.

In my mind it would look somewhat like this:

[image: drag and drop in edit mode][image: normal mode]

(that ugly thing there is supposed to be a mouse courser)

Some thoughts and things to consider that may or may not be useful:

- The same could be done for ignored tags. But do people really click on tags they ignore? If not, there wouldn't be much use in reordering them. The ui should be consistent though.
- There could be a *save* and *cancel* button in edit mode, removed tags could temporally be made transparent until saved - just like questions are made transparent when adding an ignored tag. Would it annoy users who go to another page without saving? Immediate changed might be better.
- The *prefs* tab in the user profile could act the same, or it could be always in edit mode.
- Showing and hiding the [image: x] changes the width and could cause tags to appear in other lines.
- The [image: x] could be made [more visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77082/remove-favorite-and-ignore-tags#comment-187654) without disturbing the normal design [image: x].

Comment: I accidentally removed my _first_ tag the other day, re-adding it put it right at the bottom - now I need to scroll on all my laptops just to click the _only_ tag I ever really click - you read my mind with this request (though, nothing so intricate, I just want to order them.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61704/152009

Comment: And, re the linked question: removing 29 tags just to place _one_ in the 'correct' slot is awfully inefficient.

Comment: Looks like the edit button has been implemented. A feature to reorder tags would still be nice though.